# Limits on Vector Spaces on the Real Line?

Tags: limits, vector-spaces

I am a bit confused with the notion of limits on an arbitrary finite dimensional vector space  $X$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose $x\in X$ and $\{r_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. Is it true that $(\lim_{n\to \infty}r_n)x = \lim_{n\to \infty}(r_nx)$?

I am confused because most such vector spaces I have worked with before have been equipped with a norm or a metric but the limit on the right hand side here is purely topological, and I haven't been able to rigorously prove the above to myself. Any help is much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: If the vector space is endowed with a vector space topology, the vector space operations (addition, scalar multiplication) are continuous, hence you have $(\lim r_n)\cdot x = \lim (r_n\cdot x)$ then.

Comment: Ah! You're right Daniel Fischer, thanks very much. I didn't think of this =D